# How to create fine-grained texture for background?

Tags: texture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a “pixeled” Background](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/create-a-pixeled-background)

I want to create popular fine-grained texture for background. I don't know how it's called in a right way so I even can not even google any tutorials. Examples can be found everywhere: in twitter header, picture below or even this site light blue background.

I'd like to know how this technique is called and will be happy to see some tutorials.

[image: Texture example]

Comment: That specific texture would likely be 'film grain' which is caused by the film itself. As hamstu points out, adding noise is an easy way to create that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture you're referring to is the result of a simple *noise* filter. In Photoshop it's acceisble via **Filter -> Noise -> Add Noise...**

To recreate the effect seen on this site, and also in yor attatched image, you'll want settings like this:

- *Amount*: 5-10%
- *Distribution*: Your preference (I usually choose Guassian)
- Check *Monochromatic*

You can adjust the Amount to your liking. Also, be sure you're applying this Filter to a non-empty layer. (So fill it with white or blue, for example)