# How to recreate this background in photoshop for use in a mobile app?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, patterns, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do so many app menus get that finished textured look?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/how-do-so-many-app-menus-get-that-finished-textured-look)

I'm still a beginner, but I really like this texture and have been trying for hours to recreate it.

**Question:** How can one make this kind of texture in photoshop? (the black background behind the navigation menu)

[image]

It doesn't seem to be a standard color+noise combination. At least not one that I was able to come up with.

For use in a mobile app, I assume it would be best to just 10x10px png and repeat it x/y?

Comment: And.. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/create-a-pixeled-background

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't mean to duplicate. My only defense is that I don't believe it's made with noise like the other link.

Comment: No problem. :) It's monochromatic noise though... a transparent noise image over CSS colors. Either that or a small noise image repeated.

Comment: Hmmm...there seems to be some disagreement :)  See Marius's answer below.

Comment: Same answer.. it's a noise pattern.. so it's just semantics. It's still noise, but probably a seamless pattern as well.

Comment: Read Marc Edward's Answer in the first link in these comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some noise with lines to me. While I didn't match it perfectly, this seems pretty close. Left = original, right = my version.

### Step 1: Fill and noise.

Fill with a dark grey, chosen from the original, then add some noise (Filter > Noise > Add Noise). You only need a few percent of noise, and monochrome noise is probably best for something like this.

[image]

### Step 2: Lines.

On another layer, add some white lines.

[image]

### Step 3: Line opacity.

Reduce the white line layer opacity to about 5%.

[image]

Not identical, but kind of close. If this is for an iOS app, the big question might be how to build for Retina and non-Retina sizes, while still maintaining quality and scalability. In that situation, I'd keep create the noise, save is as a pattern, use it via a pattern layer, then add the lines as a shape layer. Then, I'd use David Jensen's Scale Patterns to 100% script to ensure the noise stays crisp at all sizes (let me know if you'd like a link for the script).

Comment: This probably breaks some kind of rule, but the post   involves your work so I thought I'd ask: Can you take a look at this question [link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280871/proper-way-to-display-clicked-state-of-a-button-in-the-navigation-menu-of-an-ios] when you get a chance? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's a pattern, applied in Blending Options.

You can try to find that texture already made, or recreate it yourself (in Edit -> Define pattern).

Few sites: http://www.brusheezy.com/patterns, http://myphotoshopbrushes.com/patterns/, http://psd.fanextra.com/articles/photoshop-patterns/ or simply [Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&spell=1&q=photoshop%20patterns&sa=X&ei=uJLFUOe4MsbJswawkIHgBQ&ved=0CDMQvwUoAA&biw=1527&bih=848)